# Black Flickering while Dismissing PopOverViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I'm getting black flickering screen while dismissing PopOverViewController.

Code in ViewController.swift

```
 if segue.identifier == "addComment"
    {   
               let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileCommentPopOver
                controller.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
                controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 150)
               controller.fetchedProfileID = sendToUserID
        }
```

PopOverViewController.swift

```
 @IBAction func addCommentAction(sender: UIButton)
{
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

[image: Please check screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@IBAction func addCommentAction(sender: UIButton)
{
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:{})
}
```

Comment: Error. [has no member 'dismiss']

Comment: Anyone ? Any solution ? Struggling with problem since long time.